# Incorrect indentation for the "end" word of a for loop

Tags: indentation, algorithms

I'm writing a pseudo code in latex using `algorithm` package, however, I have problem with indentation of the last `end` word for the `for`-loop if this `for`-loop contains an `if` statement. If it doesn't contain the `if` statement, all looks fine.

Example with no `if` statement and correct indentation:

[image: Correct indentation]

Example with an `if` statement and incorrect indentation:

[image: Incorrect indentation]

The code used to generate the latter one is following (just remove the `if` part to get the code used for first example):

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Test algorithm}
    \SetAlgoLined

    \For{$ t \in T $}{
        $t \gets $ 1

         \If{ (t) \in P} {
            t \gets 0

         }
    }

\end{algorithm}
```

Do you know how can this be fixed?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about "using algorithm package"? The `\SetAlgoLined` seems to be introduced by the `algorithm2e` package. Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question? Also, do you recieve any error messages? If so, please don't ignore then. Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your usage of `\SetAlgoLined` I assume that you are actually using the `algorithm2e` package. If I make a MWE with this package, I recieve the following error message `Missing $ inserted.` that is caused by `\in` and `\gets` being used in text mode in line 12 and 13. If I add the missing `$`s, the MWE compiles perfectly fine and gives the desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Test algorithm}
    \SetAlgoLined

    \For{$ t \in T $}{
        $t \gets $ 1

         \If{ $(t) \in P$} {
            $t \gets 0$

         }
    }

\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly the problem and sorry for stating misleading package name!